# Adjusting the postion of chapter numbers in the Tufte-Latex class

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, tufte

I'm using the [Tufte-latex](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/) book class, and trying to figure out how to use numbers in the chapters/sections.

The default style has no numbers, which I turned off by commenting out this line:

```
% Turn off section numbering
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

But I can't figure out how to make the Chapter Number, and Chapter Title be on the same line. At the moment the chapter title is underneath the number like so:

[image]

while I would prefer the chapter to look more like other sections, e.g.:

[image]

I've read through the class file a few times, but I'm not sure what I should be looking for as I'm not familiar with many of the commands. I think this section may be relevant, but am not certain:

(lines 1526 - 1534)

```
% Make Tuftian-style section headings and TOC formatting

\titleformat{\chapter}%
  [display]% shape
  {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}% format applied to label+text
  {\itshape\huge\thechapter}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}% before the title body
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]% after the title body
```

And possibly this part:

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
```

I would appreciate any guidance about how to tweak this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You found the relevant section, the `display` option is causing this numbering style. Change it for example to `hang` to get a hanging label, such as with `\section.`

[`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) is the package providing such headings. The [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) explains options and syntax.

Besides the command reference for `\titleformat` and `\titlesection` this documentation provides a set of examples in its appendix, which produce the well known appearance of standard LaTeX headings. This is a great start for starting customizing headings.

You can also make it similar to the `\titleformat{\section}` lines in the class file, just changing sizes and spacing.

Keep in mind, if you copy commands from a class file for using in your own preamble, use [`\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother`afterwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do), if a macro contains an `@` symbol.

Comment: Great - thanks for the hints. I played around with it and managed to fix it by just copying the formatting of the `\section`

Comment: Could you please post what your solution was? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 9):

Since Forkrul Assail's request wasn't answered, I tried to solve it myself. I ended up copying the definition from tufte-common.def and adjusting it with the [block]-shape instead of [display] and increasing the horizontal separator from 0pt to 1em. So I put the following in my preamble:

```
  \titleformat{\chapter}
  [block]% shape
  {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}% format applied to label+text
  {\itshape\huge\thechapter}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}% before the title body
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]% after the title body
```

Ending up with this:

[image: adjusted tufte chapter with numbering on single line]

If someone comes here and wonders how to get chapter numbers you just need

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

in your preamble.